# BASH How to save the output of rm -vri to a var

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

How can I save the output of this command into a var and still remove the files?

```
rm -vri files | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is very precise, the answer is short

`VAR=$(rm -vri files | wc -l)`

**Update** 
just in case one has more interest on the subject, here is the link to [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#COMMANDSUBREF)

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like

```
rm -vri *.txt | tee rm.out
```

just make sure your rm wildcard pattern does not cover the output file